# ASR920 - port Te0/0/3-tefp1 is not a router port on Vlan 217

Tags: cisco, router, igmp, pim

When I enabled debugging:

```
PIM#debug ip igmp snooping router
```

I get in logs:

```
Mar 30 15:58:36.275: IGMPSN: router: port Te0/0/3-tefp1 is not a router port on Vlan 217
```

Configuration for interfaces:

```
interface TenGigabitEthernet0/0/3
 description DOWNLINK for STB
 no ip address
 flowcontrol receive off
 service-policy output QOS-SGT
 service instance trunk 1 ethernet
  encapsulation dot1q 209-225
  rewrite ingress tag pop 1 symmetric
  bridge-domain from-encapsulation
end

interface BDI217
 description VID 217 for STB
 ip address 10.200.199.1 255.255.255.128
 ip broadcast-address 10.200.199.127
 ip helper-address 10.200.200.31
 no ip redirects
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip pim sparse-mode
end
```

What's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Why do you think anything is wrong? Is that really the only thing the debug is showing? Is anything not working as expected or are you just curious what that debug message means?

Comment: I have problems with STB: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/stb-generate-igmp-leave-without-reason