# STB generate IGMP Leave without reason

Tags: multicast, igmp, pim

In my network STB generates IGMP Leave (in STB logs "End of Stream") without any reason or there is something what I don't understand.

There is one exeption STB directly connected to PIM (ASR920) working fine only errors I find in logs are "TS Continuity Counter Error".

All others STB connected to switches behind PIM experience in logs "STBPlayer[0]: End of Stream". Dump from tcpdump shows only "IGMP Leave" and after second STB rejoin multicast group with "IGMP Membership Report". It happen in random time, random vlans and the problem intensifies in the evening. Whe have we have enough bandwidth. I check every counter what I know in PIM (asr920) and didnt't find any errors, drops, misses, failures, etc.

In addition mu;lticast group UPTIME in PIM coincides with the time when STB has left the group itself.

Example:

```
Apr 19 12:21:05 stbapp: STBPlayer: End of Stream.
```

After 2 min and 43 seconds:
PIM#show ip igmp groups 239.239.5.2

```
IGMP Connected Group Membership
Group Address    Interface                Uptime    Expires   LastReporter
239.239.5.2      BDI225                   00:02:43  00:02:35  0.0.0.0
```

After 5 min and 52 seconds:
PIM#show ip igmp groups 239.239.5.2

```
IGMP Connected Group Membership
Group Address    Interface                Uptime    Expires   LastReporter
239.239.5.2      BDI225                   00:05:52  00:02:20  10.200.249.140
```

Behind ASR920 is N3K-C3064PQ-10GE then DCN,DLINK and other vendors.

PIM ASR920 use sparse-mode and igmp snooping v2

```
Global IGMP Snooping configuration:
-------------------------------------------
IGMP snooping Oper State     : Enabled
IGMPv3 snooping (minimal)    : Enabled
Report suppression           : Enabled
TCN solicit query            : Disabled
Robustness variable          : 2
Last member query count      : 2
Last member query interval   : 1000
Check TTL=1                  : No
Check Router-Alert-Option    : No

Vlan 225:
--------
IGMP snooping Admin State           : Enabled
IGMP snooping Oper State            : Enabled
IGMPv2 immediate leave              : Disabled
Report suppression                  : Enabled
Robustness variable                 : 2
Last member query count             : 2
Last member query interval          : 1000
Check TTL=1                         : Yes
Check Router-Alert-Option           : Yes
```

NEXUS3000

```
Global IGMP Snooping Information:
  IGMP Snooping enabled
  IGMPv1/v2 Report Suppression enabled
  IGMPv3 Report Suppression disabled
  Link Local Groups Suppression enabled
  VPC Multicast optimization disabled

IGMP Snooping information for vlan 225
  IGMP snooping enabled
  Lookup mode: IP
  IGMP querier present, address: 10.200.249.129, version: 2, i/f Eth1/8
  Switch-querier disabled
  IGMPv3 Explicit tracking disabled
  IGMPv2 Fast leave disabled
  IGMPv1/v2 Report suppression enabled
  IGMPv3 Report suppression disabled
  Link Local Groups suppression enabled
  Router port detection using PIM Hellos, IGMP Queries
  Number of router-ports: 1
  Number of groups: 32
  VLAN vPC function disabled
  Active ports:
    Eth1/7      Eth1/8  Eth1/17 Eth1/18
    Eth1/19     Eth1/43 
  Report Flooding: Disabled
  Interfaces for Report Flooding: n/a 
  Use Group Address for Proxy Leaves: no

vlan configuration 225
  ip igmp snooping mrouter interface Ethernet1/8
  no ip igmp snooping explicit-tracking
  ip igmp snooping version 2
```

**What could it be? How can I identify the source of the problem?**